# express handlebars render to string instead of response

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I currently use express handlebars successfully - however I want to use it for updating and rendering only a piece of a page - a list of items that changes over time, so I want to update *just that list* on a timer.   Essentially on the browser I have the following code:

```
$.get( "myUrl").then( result => $("#targetdiv").html( result.html ));
```

so on the server for every page I've been doing something like this:

```
app.get("/myUrl", async (req, res) => {res.render( "someTemplateFile");} )
```

however, clearly those two don't work together - I need do so something like this:

```
app.get("/myUrl", async (req, response) => 
{
   var renderedHtml =   .....someCodeHere...... ("someTemplateFile");
   response.send( {html:renderedHtml} );
}
```

Is there an easy way of doing that?

Comment: `res.render` does the same thing - it creates HTML and sends to browser. Why do you say "they don't work together"?

Comment: I guess I wanted it as json - I've had security problems trying to return html as html before from jquery ajax type functions - but json always seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [render](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars#user-content-renderfilepath-context-options) API like this:

```
var hb = require('express-handlebars').create();
app.get("/myUrl", async (req, response) => 
{
   hb.render("some.hbs",{title:"Title",body:"Body"}).then((renderedHtml) => {
       response.send( {html:renderedHtml} );
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
app.get("/myUrl", (req, res) => {
  res.render(
    'template',
    dataObject,
    (err, rawHtml) => {
      if(!err) {
        console.log(rawHtml)
        res.send(rawHtml)
      }
    }
  )
})
```

Comment: it works perfectly, thank you, I had no idea the function `render` had a last parameter